# Secure way to run other people code (sandbox) on my server?

Tags: linux, security, virtualization, sandbox

I want to make a web service that runs other people's code locally. Naturally, I want to limit their code's access to a certain "sandbox" directory, so that they won't be able to connect to other parts of my server (DB, main webserver, etc.)

What's the best way to do this?

**Run VMware/Virtualbox:**

- + I guess it's as secure as it gets. Even if someone manage to "hack", they only hack the guest machine
- + Can limit the CPU & memory the processes use
- + Easy to set up - just create the VM
- - Harder to "connect" the sandbox directory from the host to the guest
- - Wasting extra memory and CPU for managing the VM

**Run underprivileged user:**

- + Doesn't waste extra resources
- + Sandbox directory is just a plain directory
- ? Can't limit CPU and memory?
- ? I don't know if it's secure enough

**Any other way?**

Server running Fedora Core 8, the "other" codes written in Java & C++

Comment: More on topic at: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/32375/how-to-run-clients-code-on-server-securely

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run user-submitted scripts securely in a node.js sandbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446729/how-to-run-user-submitted-scripts-securely-in-a-node-js-sandbox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Running under unprivileged user still allows a local attacker [to exploit vulnerabilities to elevate privileges](http://it.slashdot.org/article.pl?sid=08/02/10/2011257).
2. Allowing to execute code in a VM can be insecure as well; the attacker can gain access to host system, as recent [VMWare vulnerability report](http://www.publicsafety.gc.ca/prg/em/ccirc/2009/av09-017-eng.aspx) has shown.

In my opinion, allowing running native code on your system in the first place is not a good idea from security point of view. Maybe you should reconsider allowing them to run *native* code, this will certainly reduce the risk.

Comment: well.. of course it's not a good idea from a security point of view, but I need to do it, so i have to compromise.
I know that there isnt 100% security if I let other people run code (there isnt 100% security anywhere)- It's not a bank site where people have huge motivation to "hack".., I just want to get as much "Cost-Benefit" as I can.

Comment: Use some form of sandboxing, but consider disallowing running native code. Is this possible?

Comment: We could extend this argument to *"there are vulnerabilities in web servers, so you should not run a web site."*  In fact, *"there are vulnerabilities in web browsers, so you should not browse the Internet!"*

Comment: @BlueRaja, not to say that you *can't* allow users to run code at all (e.g. Google App Engine does allow you to run Java byte code), but native code has a bad track record of not turning local root vulnerabilities into remote root vulnerabilities.

Comment: Is exploiting vulnerabilities to elevate privileges still relevant in 2014?

Comment: @HelloWorld it's 2k15 and it's relevant and unless you make all privileges equal it will always be. Yeah, people code better and more secure code, but there is always some attack vector that can be tackled.

Virtualisation is probably way to go, but depending on your use case you can opt to go for something like hardened gentoo (LXC jail, selinux, ...).
This approach gives you more options, but getting it right might be challenging. Just make sure to minimize exposure to inherently insecure things (X server, video drivers).
Expected performance hit of such setup should be around 5%.

Answer (score 15):

To limit CPU and memory, you want to set limits for groups of processes (POSIX resource limits only apply to individual processes). You can do this using cgroups.

For example, to limit memory start by mounting the memory cgroups filesystem:

`# mount cgroup -t cgroup -o memory /cgroups/memory`

Then, create a new sub-directory for each group, e.g.

```
# mkdir /cgroups/memory/my-users
```

Put the processes you want constrained (process with PID "1234" here) into this group:

```
# cd /cgroups/memory/my-users
# echo 1234 >> tasks
```

Set the total memory limit for the group:

`# echo 1000000 > memory.limit_in_bytes`

If processes in the group fork child processes, they will also be in the group.

The above group sets the resident memory limit (i.e. constrained processes will start to swap rather than using more memory). Other cgroups let you constrain other things, such as CPU time.

You could either put your server process into the group (so that the whole system with all its users fall under the limits) or get the server to put each new session into a new group.

Answer (score 9):

[`chroot`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/chroot), [jail](http://www.jmcresearch.com/projects/jail/), [container](http://lxc.sf.net), [VServer](http://linux-vserver.org)/[OpenVZ](http://openvz.org)/etc., are generally more secure than running as an unprivileged user, but lighter-weight than full OS virtualization.

Also, for Java,  you might trust the JVM's built-in sandboxing, and for compiling C++, [NaCl](http://code.google.com/p/nativeclient/) claims to be able to sandbox x86 code.

But as Checkers' answer states, it's been proven possible to cause malicious damage from almost any "sandbox" in the past, and I would expect more holes to be continually found (and hopefully fixed) in the future.  Do you *really* want to be running untrusted code?

Answer (score 9):

Reading the codepad.org/about page might give you some cool ideas.

http://codepad.org/about

Answer (score 1):

Check out `ulimit` and friends for ways of limiting the underprivileged user's ability to DOS the machine.

Answer (score 1):

Try learning a little about setting up policies for SELinux.  If you're running a Red Hat box, you're good to go since they package it into the default distro.

This will be useful if you know the things to which the code should not have access.  Or you can do the opposite, and only grant access to certain things.

However, those policies are complicated, and may require more investment in time than you may wish to put forth.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Ideone API](http://ideone.com/api/) - the simplest way.

Comment: Ideone API limits the number of requests to 1000 per month. That's one of the reasons I want to create my own online judge.

Comment: @SinnerShanky If you need an online judge service then there is a lot of ready made services. E.g. [DOMjudge](http://domjudge.sourceforge.net/) is the one you might install at your own server. You might also use [SPOJ](http://spoj.com) which is the one which allows to set customizable contest (and uses the same engine as ideone).
BTW: Ideone allows more submissions in the charged option.

Answer (score 1):

try using lxc as a container for your apache server

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about how much effort you want to put into this thing but could you run Xen like the VPS web hosts out there?

http://www.xen.org/

This would allow full root access on their little piece of the server without compromising the other users or the base system.