# How to run user-submitted scripts securely in a node.js sandbox?

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

What are the options for running (possibly malicious) user-submitted scripts in node.js, securely?  I.e. in an environment that prevents code from accessing sensitive data and APIs?

`vm.runInNewContext(userScript, {})` is a tempting starting point... but it seems like there are [known issues](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/1469) there.

The [sandbox module](https://github.com/gf3/sandbox) looks interesting, but uses `runInNewContext()` as well so I'm a bit leery of it.

Comment: I'd recommend using `vm` because it's part of node core. And since node core tends to gets its bugs fixed just assume it the issue will be fixed

Comment: @Raynos it's not a bug. The docs say it's only intended for known-good code.

Comment: @thejh - true, but the API does lend itself toward the pretty reasonable belief that the code is executing in an entirely different context, implying that said code shouldn't be able to access the current context.  And I expect that the *intent* of the API is exactly that - to provide a sandbox in which to run scripts.

So... I think a pretty strong case can be made that this is simply a well-documented bug. :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run untrusted code serverside?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10937870/how-to-run-untrusted-code-serverside)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You should always run untrusted code in a separate process, which is exactly what the sandbox module does. A simple reason is that `vm.runInNewContext('while(true){}', {})` will freeze node.

It starts by spawning a separate process, which will later send the result serialized to JSON on its stdout. The parent process continues executing regardless of what the child does and can trigger a timeout.

The untrusted code is then wrapped in a closure with [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Strict_mode) (in regular JavaScript, you can use `arguments.callee.caller` to access data outside of your scope). Finally, a very limited `global` object is passed to prevent access to node's API. The untrusted code can only do basic computation and has no access to files or sockets.

While you should read sandbox's code as an inspiration, I wouldn't recommend using it as is:

- The code is getting old and hasn't been updated for 7 months.
- The Child Process module in node already provides most of the features you need, especially [child_process.fork()](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options).
- The IPC channel provided by child_process.fork probably has better performances.

For increased security, you could also consider using [setuid-sandbox](http://code.google.com/p/setuid-sandbox/). It's the code used by Google Chrome to prevent tab processes from accessing the file system. You would have to make a native module, but this [example](http://code.google.com/p/setuid-sandbox/source/browse/example.c) seems straightforward.

Comment: The methods in the `vm` module now support a `timeout` parameter which lets you safely execute `while(true) {}`. It obviously doesn't address the security concerns, but it does address endless loops.

Comment: @AndrewPaprocki Can you link to the docs where timeout is shown?

Comment: This answer is very good. Still, I want to point to another similar question (more recent) which may be helpful to people with the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17513212/safely-sandbox-and-execute-user-submitted-javascript

Answer (score 16):

There is [a newer module on github called vm2](https://github.com/patriksimek/vm2) that addresses some of these concerns, especially in Node.JS applications. Maybe that will help some others find it, as I have just done.