# Javascript / My dynamic function is it safe?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, eval

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to run user-submitted scripts securely in a node.js sandbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446729/how-to-run-user-submitted-scripts-securely-in-a-node-js-sandbox)

I want that my user can create their own format function that work with a particular object. I find two ways of doing it but I don't know if that functions can be hacked. It is run inside nodeJS.

```
//First way with eval (evil ?)
function convertObj(formula) {
   return function (obj) {
        return eval(formula);
    };
}

// Second way with function (same as eval ?)
function convertObj2(formula) {
  return new Function("obj", "return " + formula);
}

var inst = {
      "name": "BOB",
      "age": "30"    
    };

var formula = "obj.name.toLowerCase() + ' is ' + obj.age + ' years old'";

var next = convertObj(formula);
var next2 = convertObj2(formula);

document.write('<p>' + next(inst) + '</p>');
document.write('<p>' + next2(inst) + '</p>');​
```

Print

```
bob is 30 years old
bob is 30 years old
```

The example is also available at http://jsfiddle.net/DeWYy/2/

Comment: [Both are bad](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/11/01/53329.aspx), but hey depending on what you're actually trying to do there might not be any other way!

Comment: both versions are `eval`ed, there is no difference. And yes, they can be abused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are vulnerable, because you are literally leaving anyone run anything without any control.

What you probably want to do is run the code inside a sandbox. There are library that will help you with that (a quick Google search comes up with [Sandbox](http://gf3.github.com/sandbox/)). Do note that even if you run user-submitted code in a sandbox there will always be risk, but they are mostly mitigated. So unless you run a critical service, it can be consider secure.

I also recommend you to take a look at this question about running user-submitted code securely.

- [How to run user-submitted scripts securely in a node.js sandbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446729/how-to-run-user-submitted-scripts-securely-in-a-node-js-sandbox)