# how to restrict global variables or functions in node js

Tags: node.js, express

**how to restrict global variables and functions in node js?**

like: require method

i want to limit use of require method. 
i don't want any node app to access "fs" in my node framework which i build on top of express, they can only require modules which i want them to.
and also i want to restrict access to process, global scope .

suppose when i load any js library for any app

like:

```
var x=require('app1.js');
```

in my framework

then i want to make sure this app1.js cannot access filesystem using require("fs")

**app1.js**

```
var x=require("fs");
exports.hello=function(){
   console.log(typeof x.readSync);
}
```

i want this console to print undefined;

**and in this sample**

```
var x=require("helper.js");
exports.hello=function(){
   console.log(typeof x.hello);
}
```

i want this console to print function;

thanks in advance

Comment: Sandboxing 3rd party code is well described in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11796148/1762886

Comment: can vm return object after executing code in different context ? and can i pass arguments to vm which will be available inside?

Answer (score 1):

I'd create a new function that will act like require.

```
requireSafe = function(param){
    if(!isAllowedLogic(param)) return null;
    else return require(param);
}
```

And when someone submits code, you append `var require;` at the top to prevent them to use the regular `require`. Or you search in their submission and only approve it if it doesn't contain `require` nor `eval`.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to do that?

It is not possible to change the way require works, as it is a build-in node.js function.

Comment: i made a simple framework to host users server code, and i don't want them to access filesytem and similar api. that's why i want to restrict or abstract require method.

Comment: then you should do this using UNIX chroot and building a secure sandbox. node, however, is not the correct place to do that. http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot

Comment: i expected to find some work around in javascript instead of low level coding. i have got way to restrict user using eval but i have doubt whether its secure or not.

Comment: using a chroot is not "low level coding". its simple unix setup and the only thing that will help you with your problem. using eval as a security mechanism is the worst thing you can do, really - you'll end up writing your own javascript interpreter - just spend a few hours and learn about chroots - for real

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://github.com/asvd/jailed) library,
for a bit of detail of how its security works, from the README :

> A Node.js subprocess is created by the Jailed library;
>
> the subprocess (down)loads the file containing an untrusted code as a
>   string (or, in case of DynamicPlugin, simply uses the provided string
>   with code)
>
> then "use strict"; is appended to the head of that code (in order to
>   prevent breaking the sandbox using arguments.callee.caller);
>
> finally the code is executed using vm.runInNewContext() method, where
>   the provided sandbox only exposes some basic methods like
>   setTimeout(), and the application object for messaging with the
>   application site.