# Javascript - Make variables declared in eval - or new Function - go inside a context object

Tags: javascript, node.js, eval

For a NodeJS standalone app, I need the ability to parse arbitrary JS code. This app is offline, and does not interact with anything else than the user input: I can use `eval` or `new Function()` without security risk.

However, a user can create a variable inside its code. I would like this variable to be created not inside a global space, but inside a custom context object I would give.

For example, getting something like this:

```js
let context = {a: 5}
new Function('context', '/*something*/ console.log("a =", a); let b = -5;')(context)
console.log('context is', context)
```

Would output

```
a = 5
context is {a: 5, b: -5}
```

Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: Looks like you want https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Safely sandbox and execute user submitted JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17513212/218196)

Comment: @FelixKling Exactly what I wanted! Thank you, can you add it as an answer so I can validate it ? (else I'll answer myself later)