# How to prevent exec from performing write operations?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to build an online compiler for various languages. Here is a snippet of what I am trying to do.

```
const util = require('util');
const exec = util.promisify(require('child_process').exec);

exec('node node_temp.js').then(result => {
    console.log(result);
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

So in case of JavaScript(Node).The user will type in some code and send it via a POST request, then the code will be copied into `node_temp.js`and then will be executed.

Now there is a chance that the user might use `fs` or any other means to delete all the files in system. How do I prevent my `exec()` function to modify any system files.

Some answers suggest using `vm` or `vm2`. I have used both, although it creates a new sandbox, the `exec` command still gives access to the manipulate local files.

Comment: provide a button to compile and run the code don't let the user input the command. Azure already provide such facility how much I know. In case of Linux or Mac you have to create proper administrative structure in your system so the user can not modify anything .

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45767337/running-untrusted-javascript-code-on-server-in-sandbox