# How to run a JavaScript function in a sandbox environment?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an application server written in JavaScript(node.js) . I accept a JS function code as an input from the web browser.
Now I want to be able to run this function on server without affecting anything else.

I want to make sure that all the variables this function is modifying are local to the function and not affecting any other vars on server.

Also I would like to somehow avoid infinite loops or recursions and any other unforseen problems.

Mostly I would like the user to be able to trigger some code as a function to be run before I take some action.

Any ideas ?

Comment: No can do.  Once you're running arbitrary code you're doing just that - running arbitrary code.

Comment: second that!  Short of firing a separate node instance, there is not enough in V8 to guarantee full sandboxing.  I wish there was!

Comment: I don't know if http://jsapp.us/ runs the code on the server but if so you probably want to check it out! https://github.com/matthewfl/node-host

Comment: Your best bet is to probably read up on the [vm module](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/vm.html) in node.js. Not sure there's going to be a bullet-proof way to execute arbitrary code, but figured I would at least mention this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run untrusted code serverside?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10937870/how-to-run-untrusted-code-serverside)

Comment: @Jerska What's point of this 7 years later? I don't even remember why I asked it.

Comment: This is an automatic message when flagging as a duplicate. There are many questions about the same topic, and I flagged them as duplicates to link them together.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Sandbox](https://github.com/gf3/sandbox) is a node module that according to the README;

- Can be used to execute untrusted code
- Support for timeouts (e.g. prevent infinite loops)
- Restricted code (cannot access node.js methods)

[The Halting Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) as [@maerics wrote about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14889393/how-to-run-a-javascript-function-in-a-sandbox-environment/14898901#14898901) can be solved by setting a timeout for the code although you can not do that in the same process, because for example `while(1)` will block it. Sandbox addresses this issue by using a child process.

The variable problem should therefore also be solved because Sandbox is in a child process and not the main process.

As mentioned before, if possible, you should avoid users to run arbitrary code on your server because it comes with an *huge* security risk. Even through the module provides this restrictions you should run at least the child processes with an as unprivileged user as possible.

Answer (score 3):

#### You cannot programmatically determine if arbitrary code will run indefinitely or terminate.

This is called [The Halting Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

You might be able to prevent arbitrary JS code from modifying variables other than the ones it creates by sandboxing in a separate process.

Either way, accepting arbitrary code for execution on a server is opening a huge security risk on your system.  Think carefully about how you can avoid it.

Comment: I might keep a timeout for infinite execution. its the vars I am worried about.