# Prevent system calls in Node.js when running untrusted user code

Tags: javascript, node.js, user-defined-functions

I am currently considering issues of running user-supplied code in node. I have two issues:

1. The user script must not read or write global state. For that, I assume I can simply spawn of a new process. Are there any other considerations? Do I have to hide the parent process from the child somehow, or is there no way a child can read, write or otherwise toy with the parent process?
2. The user script must not do anything funky with the system. So, I am thinking of disallowing any system calls. How do I achieve this? (Note that if I can disallow the process module, point 1 should be fixed as well, no?)

Comment: What OS are you running on?

Comment: I want this to work on all systems (at least Windows and Linux).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run untrusted code serverside?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10937870/how-to-run-untrusted-code-serverside)

Comment: @Jerska From what I understand, these days, [`vm2`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vm2) seems to be the way to go

Comment: This is an automatic message when marking as a duplicate.`vm2` would be the way to go to run a `node` process, but requires careful maintenance on any new `node` release. If you're looking to execute raw JavaScript, `isolated-vm` would be a better alternative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for the `runInNewContext` function from the `vm` module ([vm documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/vm.html)).

When you use this function it creates a VERY limited context. You'll need to pass anything you want into the sandbox object which become global objects. For example: You will need to include `console` in the sandbox object if you want your untrusted code to write to the console.

Another thing to consider: Creating a new context is a VERY expensive operation - takes extra time and memory to do. Seriously consider if you absolutely need this. Also seriously consider how often this is going to happen.

Example:

```
var vm = require('vm');
var sandbox = {
    console: console,
    msg: "this is a test",
};

vm.runInNewContext('console.log(msg);', sandbox, 'myfile.vm');

// this is a test
```

More to consider: You will want to create a new process to run this in. Even though it's in a new context it's still in the same process that it's being called from. So a malicious user could simply set a never ending `for` loop so that it never exits. You'll need to figure out logic to know when something like this happens so that you can kill the process and create a new one.

Last thought: A new context does not have `setTimeout` or `setInterval`. You may or may not want to add these. However, if you create a `setInterval` in the untrusted code and the untrusted code never stops it then it will continue on forever. You'll need to figure a way to end the script, it's probably possible I just haven't looked into it.

Comment: Thank you. This is extremely helpful. The last point has also been brought to my attention recently as a major issue when running Node as a server: Scripts can easily kill the whole thing. Are there standard "system tools" for Node to fix that? About the cost of context (and even process) creation: Would you recommend pooling those? Like for example, Apache just creates a threadpool of 200 threads by default. I imagine, a similar strategy might be useful for my approach (and restart contexts/processes if they die), what do you think?

Comment: I honestly don't know enough to help. I was looking into doing something similar with running untrusted code. However, I quickly moved away from it due to these issues and  didn't do enough research to find out exactly what I did need. I didn't want a single malicious user causing issues with any other users code at any point. So for my application I scraped the idea of user submitted code altogether.