# node.js runInNewContext with untrusted code

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, exploit

According to the node.js [vm module docs](http://nodejs.org/api/vm.html#vm_vm_runinnewcontext_code_sandbox_filename):

> Note that running untrusted code is a tricky business requiring great
>   care. To prevent accidental global variable leakage,
>   `vm.runInNewContext` is quite useful, but safely running untrusted code
>   requires a separate process.

If I want to build an untrusted code runner (for example, an online node.js console), this would be my natural approach:

1. Each session of untrusted code would spawn a new process using the `child_process` module, which could be killed after a certain amount of time
2. The child process would use runInNewContext to run the code

Would this be a safe approach? What would I have to watch out for?

Comment: `global variable leakage` means you can retrieve global variable. I think the sandboxed code can still reach global vars but any modification/addition would stay in the sandbox.

Comment: Hmmm... that doesn't sound particularly dangerous, unless the website owner has done something silly like `global.fs = require('fs')`. The only dangers I've been able to think of involve infinite loops/recursion.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run untrusted code serverside?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10937870/how-to-run-untrusted-code-serverside)