# nodejs: run module in sandbox

Tags: javascript, node.js, sandbox

I have this turn-based NodeJs gaming app in which developers (anyone) can submit a player-robot. My NodeJS app will load all players and let them play against each other. Because I don't know anything about the code submitted I need to run it inside a sandbox.

For example, the following untrusted code might look like this:

```
let history = [];

export default class Player {
    constructor () {
        this.history = [];
    }

    move (info) {
        this.history.push(info);
   }

   done(result) {
       history.push({result: result, history: this.history});
   }
}
```

Now, in my main app I would like to do something like

```
import Player1 from 'sandbox/player1';
import Player2 from 'sandbox/player2';
....

for (let outer = 0; outer < 10; outer ++) {
    let player1 = creeateSandboxedInstance(Player1);
    let player2 = creeateSandboxedInstance(Player2);
    for(let inner = 0; inner < 1000000; inner ++) {
        ...
        let move1 = player1.move();
        let move2 = player2.doMove();
        ...
    }
}
```

What I would like the sandbox/`creeateSandboxedInstance` environment to take care of is:

- Player class should not give access to the filesystem / internet
- Player class should not have access to app global variables
- Any state should be reseted (like class variables)
- probably more things :)

I think that I should use the [vm module](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html). Something like this probably:

```
var vm = require('vm');

var script = new vm.Script('function move(info){ ... } ...', {conext});

var sandbox = script.runInNewContext();

script.move(..);  // or
sandbox.move(..);
```

However, I cannot get it to work such that I can call the `move` method. Is something like even possible ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run untrusted code serverside?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10937870/how-to-run-untrusted-code-serverside)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do this yourself. Use an existing library. There are quite a few issues you have to deal with if you were to write it yourself. For example: How do you handle a user writing a never ending for-loop?

[How to run untrusted code serverside?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10937870/how-to-run-untrusted-code-serverside)

---

If you are planning on writing it yourself then yes, you will need the `vm` module.

By passing in an empty "sandbox" you have removed all global variables.

```
script.runInNewContext({});
```

Next you'll need to figure out how you want to handle the never ending for-loop. You'll have to create a new process to handle this scenario. Do you create 1 process to manage ALL untrusted code? If you do then you'll have to kill ALL untrusted code if a single script hangs. Do you create a new process for each untrusted code? If you do then you won't be happy with performance. Creating a new process can take a second or two. You could require the child process to "notify" the main process it's still alive. If it fails to notify within 5 seconds (or whatever your threshold is, kill the process). Note: `script.runInNewContext` does contain an option that lets you specify a "timeout" (if the code takes longer than X seconds - throw an exception), but the problem with that is it allows async code (according to another Stackoverflow post), although you could defend against that by not introducing `setTimeout`, `setInterval`, or `setImmediate` into the scope. However, even if you set it to 1 second, NO other code can run during that second in that process. So if you have 1000 scripts to run, it could take up to 1000 seconds (16 minutes) to run them all. At least running each in their own process will let them run in parallel.

Here's an example of why the timeout option won't work for you:

```
var script = new vm.Script('move = function move(info) { for(var i = 0; i < 100000; i++) { console.log(i); } }');
var sandbox = { move: null, console: console };
var result = script.runInNewContext(sandbox, { timeout: 1 });
sandbox.move('woah');
```

Next you'll need to figure out how to communicate from your main process, into a child process and then into the vm. I'm not going to get into communicating between processes as you can find that pretty easily. So, by calling `script.runInNewContext` you are executing the code right then and there. Which lets you set global variables:

```
var script = new vm.Script('move = function move(info) { console.log("test: " + info); }');
var sandbox = { move: null, console: console };
var result = script.runInNewContext(sandbox);
sandbox.move('success');
```

Comment: I figured that I had to do something with cancelling the process if it takes too long. I've created a [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32116500/nodejs-cancel-function-call-if-it-takes-too-long) for that too :) Anyway, I've done some testing with [webworker-threads](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webworker-threads) and they can be cancelled easily. So if I run the sandbox inside  a webworker it might actually work, I think

Comment: So this brings to me a new questions: Is a webworker a good sandbox ?

Comment: I don't know anything about the module - with that said - it might be a good way of creating separate processes but probably not designed as a real "sandbox".