# NodeJs: Cancel function call if it takes too long

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my Node.js app I need some sort of mechanism to stop a function call if it takes too long.

```
function testIt() { ... }

runFunctionOnlyFor(1000, testIt, function (err) {
    if (err) console.log('function call timed out');
    else console.log('function call completed successfully');
});
```

Now, of course the implementation of `runFuncOnlyFor` is unknown (to me). Any suggestions how to implement this ?

Answer (score 1):

I see some issues here.

1) You normally shouldn't write blocking code in Node.JS, even if it's "only" 1 second. If this is a web service with many clients, blocking for one second could have devastating performance effects.

2) Since Node.JS is effectively single-threaded I don't really see any easy way to cancel the execution after a certain amount of time unless the time-keeping is done by `testit` itself, since you would need a separate thread to run the function that aborts the function running in the first thread.

A better approach is likely to make the `testit` function async, and break it down into several steps with intermediate context switches, and periodically check for a flag or similar that may be set by `runFunctionOnlyFor` once a timer for the desired duration expires.

Another way is to use a [child process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) , if that suits your purposes.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I just checked [webwork-threads](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webworker-threads) which seems todo exactly what I want

Comment: I don't know how but I think it's possible to do it by inspect the event loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with Promise.race

add your long executing function in an promise and let it be p1;

create a promise which timeout on the max duration you want;

for example this promise will return after 500 mills

```
const p2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 500, 'one');
});
```

use Promise.race to collect first finishing promise

```
const response = await Promise.race([p1 , p2]);
```

if the promise p1 is taking more than 500 mills to complete then the result will be from promise p2 and the p1 will be cancel immediatly.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by creating a proxy function:

1- Store the old function in a variable

2- Create a new function that sets a timeout with a value from a param and throw an error once it timesout.

Example:

```js
async function testFunc (callback) {
  const res = await doSomeLogic();
  callback(null, res);
}

const oldTestFunc = testFunc;
async function proxiedTestFunc (timeout, callback) {
  const timeoutId = settimeout(() => {
    return callback("TIMEOUT", null);
  }, timeout);
  const res = await oldtestFunc();
  clearTimeout(timeoutId);
  callback(null, res);
}
```