# Blocking 'require' or any external access for eval call

Tags: node.js, eval

I have a node server, I'm getting a string from the users which is to be executed on a data.

So i decided to use `eval`. The problem is, any one can insert a right string which will enable access to my database. How do I prevent.

I know, I can check the string for `required()` and some other stuff, but what I want is to sandbox the whole this. I should have access to only the variables which I supply to the function in which the `eval` is.

Comment: https://github.com/asvd/jailed -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10937870/how-to-run-untrusted-code-serverside -- https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html#vm_script_runincontext_contextifiedsandbox_options

Comment: Note that checking for the string `require` is a bad idea -- you will never be able to detect `global["req"+"uire"]`, etc.